# Why does the melting point of water decreases with increase in pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, water, phase-transition

My book mentions that the melting point of water, unlike other substances, decreases with increase in temperature. But the book doesn't mentions any reason why it happens as such.I searched on the internet but couldn't find any useful insights.  My thoughts are as follows:-
*The Melting point of lead, wax etc increases with pressure because the particles become more compact thereby more thermal energy is required leading to an increase in Melting point. But why does the melting point of water decreases with increase in pressure? Why the particles of water don't become compact on increase in pressure? *

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/653220/2451